# c# How to check if a shape is selected in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, selection, shapes

I am trying to do something if a shape is selected in a worksheet. Right now, the way I am checking is not working. Here is the way I am attempting to check the selection:

```
if ((ThisAddIn.ApplicationPointer.Selection as MOIE.Shape) != null)
                {...
                }
```

To be clear ApplicationPointer is a pointer to the current application.

Even when I select an object the code inside the if statement is not executed. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you, thru c#, get to **VBA's** *TypeName()* function?? .........if yes, examine *TypeName(Selection)*

Comment: Which version of Excel are you targeting? Where are you running your code example? Perhaps [this article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2) can help you get things started.